# gambler's ruin expected stopping time

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expected-value, stopping-times

Let $(Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*}$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables following Bernoulli distribustion with parameter $p$. Let $(a,b) \in (\mathbb{N}^*)^2$. For all $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$ we put
$$
S_n = a + \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i
$$
and
$$
T = \inf \lbrace{ n \in \mathbb{N}^*  \big\vert S_n \in \lbrace 0,a+b \rbrace \rbrace }
$$
Let $\mathbb{E}_a(T) = \mathbb{E}(T \vert S_0=a)$.  Supposing that $ \mathbb{E}_a(T) $ exists for all $a$, we can find its value using the relation:
$$
\mathbb{E}_a(T)= 1+p\mathbb{E}_{a+1}(T) + (1-p) \mathbb{E}_{a-1}(T)  \quad (*)
$$
$$
\mathbb{E}_0(T) = \mathbb{E}_{a+b}(T)=0
$$
**My question:** Since $(*)$ is satisfied even if $\mathbb{E}_a(T) = +\infty$. How can I prove that $\mathbb{E}_a(T)< +\infty$ for all $a$ without using martingales. I tried with this:
$$
\mathbb{E}_a(T) = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \mathbb{P}\lbrace T>n \rbrace
$$
but i couldn't achieve the result.